# Start downloading partial azure blob before it's completed

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

Is there a form of blob (block, page, etc) that will allow this using the C# api? Machine `X` could be uploading a file to an azure blob endpoint, and machine `Y` be reading the file in real-time. I seems to me like block blob won't work, because you need to put the block list before you can query the http endpoint for it, but is there a way to query for uncommitted blocks and download those beforehand?

An example of this in practice, is that a user machine does a handshake with the server, gets a write shared access token from the server and permission to upload the file. Client #1 machine begins uploading - now say, a second client machine requests the file from the server but client #1 has not finished the upload. In this case, client #2 will get relevant details from the server, and a read-only shared access token, and then begin to read the file even though the upload has not been finished yet.

Comment: Would `machine Y` know that a blob is being uploaded? Can you describe your requirement with an example?

Comment: @GauravMantri: I added a specific example.

Comment: have you read docs about append blob? I think a well-designed append blob upload process can meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I'm inclined to say no based on my understanding of block blobs, but I want to give it a try myself first. Will revert shortly with proper answer. Regarding Append Blob, it is possible to do this but then Append Blobs are meant for different purpose (storing logs etc. where latest content always get appended) and thus may not suitable for all use cases.

Comment: @JackZeng: An append blob doesn't really have an idea of an "end", it is never-ending, but this is not true for this case. Once the client has finished the upload, it will never be appended to again - I don't think its correctly suited for this reason. I think both Page and Block blobs could probably do it (although Page Blob probably more suited), I'm just unsure of how to make it happen. Keep in mind that the server and both clients can all talk to each other during this process.

Comment: If you are willing to write each 4 MB block in serial then Append Blobs will be fine for your scenario. The reader will see the blob as it being written. Otherwise, you will need custom logic to commit the block blob at intervals (e.g. after every 100 MB of data uploaded). For this you will need to directly call PutBlock and PutBlockList with the latest block list rather than use one of the upload convenience methods.

Answer (score 0):

With `Block Blobs` I don't think it is possible to start downloading the blob while it is still being uploaded. This is simply because nothing is stored at this time. When you upload blocks for a blob, Azure  Storage simply stores the byte chunks someplace.

It is only when you commit the block list, Azure Storage creates a  block blob by arranging the byte chunks based on the request payload in commit block list operation. Even though Azure Storage [`lets to see the block list before it is committed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dd179400.aspx), it doesn't expose any API to read the contents of a block.

I don't think `Page Blob` is the correct type of blob in your scenario (same with `Append Blob`) even though the moment you write the page it gets committed in the blob and other caller can [`get the page ranges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/ee691973.aspx) and start downloading the data stored in those pages. However a page blob size has to be a multiple of 512 bytes and not all files uploaded in your application would meet this requirement.